# Doubt about EFI partition on dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

When doing a dual-boot installation (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.x) is it necessary to create an "EFI" partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFI System Partition (ESP) should already exist if Windows is preinstalled. It is part of UEFI.

Comment: It's work for my. Thanks!!!!